# Point wise mutual information of two words given a certain phrase occurs in between

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, machine-learning

I would like to compute the point wise mutual information between two words that occur in context of a certain phrase. For example if the words are 'good' and 'great', and the phrase is 'but not', then the whole phrase would be

```
good but not great
```

So we have two variables X and Y whose domain ranges over the entire vocabulary, and another random variable `R` whose domain ranges over all phrases n words long, for some appropriate n. Now I want to compute the PMI of X and Y conditioned on the fact that there is a phrase `R` (such as 'but not') occurring between them. That is I want:

$PMI(X,Y;R) = P(X,Y|R)\ln\frac{p(X,Y|R)}{p(X|R)p(Y|R)}$

However, I do not know how to express `P(X,Y|R)`. Currently I am trying to express it in terms of a first order Markov model, but that would require me to pick a value for X first, then R conditioned on X, then Y conditioned on R. However, I am already conditioning on the fact that R has been picked, so I am lost.

Any idea on how to express $P(X,Y|R)$?

Answer (score 1):

If we model the process as first order markov then the point-wise mutual information conditioned on $R$ will be 0. As$$P(X,Y|R)=P(X|R)P(Y|X,R)=P(X|R)P(Y|R)$$Using markov property in the last equality.